# import gmail contact using oauth2.0 in php

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-php-client

I have referred the following tutorial [here](http://25labs.com/import-gmail-or-google-contacts-using-google-contacts-data-api-3-0-and-oauth-2-0-in-php/)

But still I am not able to retrieve gmail contacts. Its displaying blank.
 `echo $xmlresponse` displays the following error message:

> usageLimits accessNotConfigured Access Not Configured. The API is not
>   enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer
>   restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match
>   these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update
>   your configuration. https://console.developers.google.com.

Comment: Have you enable the Contacts API in Google Console?